# javascript document height complications

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Mozilla & IE developers seem to have simultaneously changed the implementation of their height elements to represent the Opera implementation... which I previously did not have to worry about.

```
var height = (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight;
```

When performed on a blank document now returns 0 as the height of the document.  My implementation requires knowing the true client viewport to dynamically build on.  Chrome and Safari are still acting as they used to.

scrollHeight, and clientHeight are acting exactly the same.

To complicate matters document.height and document.body.offsetHeight are now also taking the full height of the document into account instead of only the viewable area as they used to... I tried an old table spacing method and used a 2000px x 1px transparent andthe document height is set to 2000 now.... naturally Chrome and Safari still work as expected and only give the viewable size.

I am very desperate to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The viewport height is not a property of the document, but of the window viewing it. You get the viewport height from `window.innerHeight`.

The stuff with `document` is only needed as a fallback for IE, which doesn't provide the `window.inner` dimensions. IE (technically incorrectly) makes the `document.documentElement` represent the viewport, so you can get the height from its `clientHeight`, unless you're in Quirks Mode which (more incorrectly) makes `document.body` represent the viewport instead. (`document.height` is totally non-standard; avoid it.)

So in summary, and assuming you need to support Quirks Mode (let's hope you don't):

```
var height= (
    'innerHeight' in window? window.innerHeight :
    document.compatMode!=='BackCompat'? document.documentElement.clientHeight :
    document.body.clientHeight
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this, that I got from [James Paldosey's site](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/):

```
function getDocHeight() {
    //utility function to find dimensions of page
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
```

Comment: No longer works for blank documents, all of those return the current document length which starts at 0 now.  I need the viewable area on a blank document.

Comment: Actually this is how jQuery is doing it (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js):

"Either scroll[Width/Height] or offset[Width/Height] or client[Width/Height], whichever is greatest. Unfortunately, this causes bug #3838 in IE6/8 only, but there is currently no good, small way to fix it."